# Contradicting theorems

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$

**Theorem 1**: If $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$ and $a>0$ then $ax\equiv ay\pmod{am}$

**Theorem 2**: $ax\equiv ay\pmod{m}\Leftrightarrow x\equiv y\pmod{\frac{m}{(a,m)}}$

---

I read these in my lecture notes and feel that they contradict.

Take $a=4,m=6$ then $(a,m)=2$

By **Theorem 1**, we have $x\equiv y\pmod{6}\Rightarrow 4x\equiv 4y\pmod{24}$

But by **Theorem 2**, $4x\equiv 4y\pmod{24}\Leftrightarrow x\equiv y\pmod{12}$

Comment: Just realised that my example is not a contradiction, but still feel that the statements contradict, if not why?

Comment: $(a,m)$ in this case is $(4,24)=4$, since $4\mid 24$, and so Theorem 2 leads you to the same statement, only with the implication arrow pointing to two directions instead of one, so Theorem 2 is simply more general.

Comment: Thanks, ill just stick to theorem 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem 1 arises from Theorem 2 when the modulus is divisible by $\,a.\,$  Thus, if we replace the modulus $\,m\,$ in Theorem 2 by $\,am\,$ then  $\,am/(a,am) = am/a = m\,$ if $\,a\ne 0,\,$ so we obtain

**Theorem**  $\ $ If $\,a\ne 0\,$ then $\ ax\equiv ay\pmod{am} \iff x\equiv y \pmod m$

This is just Theorem 1, along with its converse. So Theorem 1 is a special case of Theorem 2.